# How to add a block (which has no template) to another template

Tags: layout, blocks, layout-update

I have an extension with a Block/Tracking.php. It contains

```
class Custom_Analytics_Block_Tracking extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    protected function _toHtml() { return "Hi"; }
}
```

The layout update file contains

```
<checkout_onepage_success>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="analytics/tracking" name="analytics_tracking" />
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```

I also added in success.phtml (it looks like this is not needed!)

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('analytics_tracking'); ?>
```

But this doesn't add the return value of _toHtml() to the success page.
What am I doing wrong? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember you explicitly have to state it has to use `toHtml` output

```
<checkout_onepage_success>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="analytics/tracking" name="analytics_tracking" output="toHtml"/>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```